# Ajax is not working (don't know why)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi and thanks to everybody in advance!

I want to do a simple thing with Ajax but is not working: push the button and change the html with another one from the same folder. Is something with the javascript but I can't identify the problem. I'm quite a novice with web design.

```
$(".about .ajax").on("click",function(e){

var section = $(this).closest("section");

var href = $(this).attr("href");

$.ajax({
    url:href,
    dataType:"html",
    success:function(data){

        var contenido = $("#about",data);

        section.html(contenido);
    }
});
e.preventDefault();

});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpsdckyk/1/)

Comment: What happens? Does the request go through? Do you get an error?

Comment: Please explain *exactly* what your are trying to achieve. To code looks fine to me, but I may not do what you want it to do. Explain what you want to do. The first think you need to do is to **debug** your code and narrow down what part doesn't work. You say "Ajax doesn't work". Does that mean the request is not sent at all? Or that you don't get a response?

Comment: I thought the request didn't go through but it does for a fraction of a second. I want the current html to change by loading another html file with ajax. This occurs for a fraction of a second and then disappears, so I end up without the previous and the new html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are binding it back properly.

I think you want something like this:

```
success:function(data){
    $("#about").html(data);
}
```

Passing `data` as the 2nd argument will restrict jquery to find the right element.

Comment: The first line is grabbing the `#about` block out of the response, then `section.html(contenido)` inserts that content into the DOM.